# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer on Cloudbees cannot resolve property

Tags: spring, jenkins, cloudbees

My jenkins job copies the properties files (secret plugin) as follows

```
if [[ ! -d ~/.app ]]
then
mkdir ~/.app
fi
cp ${SECRET}/app.properties ~/.app/app.properties
```

This seems to work cos I do get

- cp /scratch/jenkins/secrets/d97a8ac1-8edc-4b15-b328-dc777d1b13c9/app.properties /home/jenkins/.app/app.properties

And my deployed war has the following configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location" value="file:///home/jenkins/.app/app.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="facebookConfig" class="com.dk.integration.fb.service.FacebookConfig">
    <property name="applicationSecret" value="${app.secret}"></property>
    <property name="applicationKey" value="${app.key}"></property>
    <property name="applicationRedirectURI" value="${app.redirecturi}"></property>
</bean>

app.properties
app.secret=...
app.key=....
app.redirecturi=http://.....
```

However, I still get
Could not resolve placeholder 'app.secret' at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport
.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)

I do not have multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEV@Cloud build slaves and RUN@Cloud server nodes are distinct hosts. Your jenkins job can't be used to prepare runtime environment. To inject such configuration, use [configuration parameters](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters)